# A group of order $595$ has a normal Sylow 17-subgroup.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups, sylow-theory

> Proof Verification: A group of order $595$ has a normal Sylow 17-subgroup.

$|G|=595=5.7.17$

The divisors of $595$ are $1,5,7,17,35,85,119,595$.

$17|n_{17}-1\implies n_{17}=1,35\\7|n_7-1\implies n_7=1,85,119\\5|n_5-1\implies n_5=1$

If possible let $n_{17}=35.$ Then there is at least $35.17-34=561$ element of order $17.$ Then $n_7=1$ for otherwise the number of elements of order $17,7$ will exceed $595!$

Let $H_5,H_7$ be the normal Sylow 5 and Sylow $7$ subgroups of $G.$ Then $H_5H_7\le G$ and since $H_5\cap H_7=(e),G=H_5\times H_7\simeq H_5\oplus H_7.$ Thus none of the $35$ elements in $H_5H_7$ is of order $17.$ Hence $G$ has at least $561+35=596$ elements!

*Please tell me whether the proof is right?*

Comment: Well, certainly $\;H_5H_7\cong H_x\times H_7\;$ as they both are normal and thus generate their own direct product, but of course $\;G\neq H_5H_7\;$ ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that every group of order $595$ is cyclic.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4266014/prove-that-every-group-of-order-595-is-cyclic)

Answer (score 2):

I'd try as follows:

Either $\;H_7\lhd G\;\;or\;\;H_{17}\lhd G\;$, otherwise we'd have *at least* $\;35\cdot 16+ 85\cdot 6=1,070 \;$ different elements in $\;G\;$ and that's impossible.

Assume thus that

$$\;H_7\lhd G\;\implies H_7H_{17}\;\;\text{is a subgroup of index $\;5\;$ in}\;\;G$$

and since $\;5\;$ is the minimal prime that divides $\;|G|\;$ we get that $\;H_7H_{17}\lhd G\;$

But then we're done since $\;H_7H_{17}\;$ is a cyclic group with an obviously normal subgroup of order $\;17\;$, and normal subgroup of normal **cyclic** subgroup is normal itself, i.e.

$$A\lhd B\lhd G\;,\;and\;\;B\;\;\text{cyclic}\;\implies A\lhd G$$

Answer (score 0):

you have count 1 twice. So your proof is not right.

Comment: Can you please explain? DonAntonio calculated $35(17-1)+85(7-1)$, so this is correct.

Comment: Of course, DonAntonoio is right. My answer is for the proof of user113578.